# can jsp access .jar files?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, properties, jar

I have a properties file in `JAR` file.

In my web application, I want to access this properties file from the `jsp` within web application.

I try doing it with the following code, but results in `FileNotFoundException`

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.properties"));
```

How can i access the file from `JAR` which is in my `classpath` within `scriptlets` in jsp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not this way.
You can try to get the Input Stream by using 'getResourceAsStream' functionality.

Read about this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("//myfile.properties");
```

Make sure your jar file which has this property file is in classpath.

Comment: thanks, the leading slash before the file name doesnot reads the file